# 5.7" 640x480 LCD GUI Design Android

Tags: android, user-interface, lcd

I want to develop an application specific  to an Android device. The device has a 5.7" 640x480 LCD touchscreen. I'm using Eclipse for development environment. I'm trying to edit "activity_main.xml" to design a GUI. There are devices which can be selected as a screen (for example: Nexus S(4.0", 480x800:hdpi), 5.1" WVGA (480x800:mdpi)).Options doesn't suit for my project. Is there a way to add a 5.7" 640x480 screen for GUI desing?

Or is it enough to change the width, height properies of RelativeLayout to 640x480?

Actually what i'm trying to say is how can I design a GUI for 640x480 LCD in Eclipse?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which device are you targeting?  I'm not aware of any android devices with 640x480 screens.

Comment: It's a custom device for project. We will use BeagleBone Black with Android OS. It has a 640x480 screen.

Comment: Ok, I see, so it's not an off-the-shelf android device then.  For your purposes, you can simply change the width and height of the AVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start "Android Virtual Device Manager"
2. Click on "Device definitions" tab
3. Click "New device"
4. Name your device and enter your device parameters
5. Create new device selecting your new device in "Device".
6. Restart Eclipse
7. Now you will be able to select your device in designer.